# CSS grid row size based on the smallest item

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this 3x3 grid. with a first column being much smaller than the others. the two other columns spans all the way. (see code example)

All items have dynamic height so i don't want to use static values to avoid any overflow.

The problem is, higher is the content in the others column, higher is the gap between items in the first column.

I'd like my items in the first column as close as possible.

is it possible with grid? without relying on an additional flexbox ?

Here a codepen with my current code
I tried to make the 2 first rows as small as possible but didn't find a way to do so.

https://codepen.io/Cobs/pen/bGZbvaQ

```css
.grid > * {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    "info options comments"
    "details options comments"
    "actions options comments";
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content auto;
}

.info {
  grid-area: info;
  align-self: start;
}

.details {
  grid-area: details;
  align-self: start;
}

.actions {
  grid-area: actions;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.options {
  grid-area: options;
  height: 400px
}

.comments {
  grid-area: comments;
  height: 800px
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="info">info</div>
  <div class="details">details</div>
  <div class="actions">actions</div>
  <div class="options">options</div>
  <div class="comments">comments</div>
</div>
```